# grunt append version number to file path string

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, protractor

In my gruntfile, I have to hardcode a file path as an argument of a task (selenium-server-standalone.jar for anyone wondering). There's only ever going to be one file in this directory, but when it gets updated, the version number suffix changes (selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar). Is there a way I can somehow compute the file path string before running this task and include it as a variable somehow?

EDIT: here is the problematic chunk of my gruntfile. `seleniumServerJar` will not accept an array

```
    //config for grunt-protractor-runner
    protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: 'test/protractor.conf.js',
            singleRun: false,
            keepAlive: false,
            noColor: false,
            args: {
                //DANGER DANGER DANGER!!! HARDCODED STRINGS
                //THIS WILL DIE WITH WEBDRIVER-MANGER UPDATE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar',
                chromeDriver: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver'
            }
        },
        run: {}
    }
```

Comment: use a glob like 'selenium-server-standalone-*.jar' ?

Comment: @MattBakaitis doesn't work :/ that was one of the first things I tried

Comment: did you use `expand` in the settings? I believe that grunt won't use the globbing patterns without it...can you post the relevant parts of your gruntfile. without it, everybody on this end of the question will be guessing what you've done and tried...

Comment: ...actually...reading the source for grunt-protractor-runner...I'm skeptical my answer below will work.  If it doesn't, I'll delete it so it doesn't confuse things.